# How to configure Unit of Work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unit-of-work

I am making progress but still struggling with Unit of Work in a multi layer MVC app. Looking at the example here: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application the UoW wraps all of the Repositories and provides each with a copy of the same dbcontext. Then the controller can use the Repositories with something like:

```
var courses = unitOfWork.CourseRepository.Get(includeProperties: "Department");
```

Now suppose You have a Service layer which accesses the Repositories instead. You could configure it so that it has a dependency on an IUnitOfWork implementation, then pass in an EfUnitOfWork implementation via Unity. Then when the Service completes some task it can call unitOfWork.context.SaveChanges(). But this approach hides the real dependencies for the Service; the repositories it needs. It also means that testing the Service requires you build a full UoW.

So I was thinking there must be a different approach and am wondering if one of the following or what I mentioned above (or something else!) is the correct approach:

- Service takes in the same repository arguments and also an IUnitOfWork. The repositories are wired up with a copy of dbContext courtesy of Unity. The EfUnitOfWork is also wired with the same copy. The Service can then use the Repositories as before and once finished use EfUnitOfWork to commit.
- Service just takes in an IUnitOfWork but sets up its required Repositories by passing to them a copy of the passed in IUnitOfWork.dbcontext

Please help!

James

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post of mine](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84), it shows IMO an elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: `DbContext` *is* a unit of work, an `DbSet` *is* a repository.  [I too have blogged about this](http://thehappypath.net/2011/11/11/entity-framework-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns/), though I still have to write another article or two to complete my thoughts.  The gist of my solution will be to reuse the generated EF code as much as possible.  In the end, you create an `IUnitOfWork`, that is `IDisposable`, has a `SaveChanges` method, and exposes `IDbSet<TEntity>` properties.  Then make a partial class of your `DbContext`, and make it implement the `IUnitOfWork` interface.

Comment: You *might* have to modify the T4 template slightly to get that partial class/interface stuff to work, and expose `IDbSet<TEntity>` properties.  In the end, your service layer would accept `IUnitOfWork`, somewhat like Anders' answer, but it would use interfaces throughout instead of concrete classes (so you wouldn't expose the `DbContext` directly).  This solution can be completely mocked/stubbed out.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, its all helping me to understand the various patterns and tools. I think for now I am going to stick with the solution i have documented below, using DbContext as the UoW, making use of EF.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Your blog is unavailable.Did you move it to some other site ?Curious to read it !

Comment: My blog isn't back online yet, though here's some initial and untested version of the idea - https://github.com/kavika13/TestableDbContextCodeGen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so having explored the issue futher I have come to the following conclusion so thought I would document here to help others or so that i can be corrected should my findings be wrong.

DbContext **is** a Unit of Work. I only need to pass this Unit of Work into the implemented EFRepository classes. It does not need to go into the Service classes. So how does a Service class call context.SaveChanges() to ensure all related changes are coordinated when it does not have an instance of DbContext? Well it calls EFRepository.Save() which looks like the following:

```
public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

With this approach, Service classes depend only on Repositories. This will be clear and can be mocked for testing. When Unity injects the required Repository objects into a Service, it can provide each Repository with the same DbContext. In addition, only Repositories have access to the DbContext.

All of this may be obvious but it had me stumped. Or it may be plain wrong, in which case please let me know!

James

Answer (score 0):

A service layer is normally designed to have each method doing a complete operation. The service layer method is responsible for handling the unit of work. Using this approach the unit of work should not span multiple calls to the service layer.

If you have larger blocks of updates that you want to do together you can use transactions. Create a new `TransactionScope` and then call several service layer methods within it:

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
  ServiceLayer.DoSomething();
  ServiceLayer.DoSomethingElse();
  ts.Commit();
}
```

Comment: My methods in the service talk to the repositories to alter the state but who calls DbContext.SaveChanges() to commit this to the db?

Comment: The service layer method calls `DbContext.SaveChanges`.

Comment: How can I ensure that the Service layer is referencing the same dbContext that the repositories are using so that all related changes are coordinated? Do I wire this up in Unity so they all use the same object?

Comment: There are several methods. The easiest is to use constructor dependency injection; pass the DbContext as a parameter to the repository's constructor. Use the most simple solution that solves your problem. Do you really need Unity?

Comment: So I could let the Service instantiate a dbContext object and then have it also create the repositories it needs, passing to them the the same dbContext object?

Comment: Thanks for your help, think I will try to simplify the app as discussed. Out of interest, can you give me a couple of pointers on how else this could be solved?

Comment: Thinking about it, this solution won't work as it prevents me from passing in mock Repositories to the Service when testing.